# Weird thread behavior when moving the printf statement below increment/decrement on "count" variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, stdthread

### **why does the program work when the printf after count++ or count-- is uncommented?**

what i am trying to do is launch 2 threads, one will increment the shared resource by 1, and the other will decrement it by 1, with the help of conditional variable and unique lock. i am very new to using threads (i started yesterday and i have no idea wth is going on).
**in func1 and func2, when you comment the printf or move it above the count++ or count--, the program stops on the 49th iteration (i.e. i=48).**

here is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include<condition_variable>

using namespace std;
int count = 0;
mutex lock1;
condition_variable c1;
int resource;
void func1()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
//        lock1.lock();
        unique_lock <mutex> lk1(lock1);

        if(count == 0)
        {
//            cout<<"thread 1 is working on resource: "<<resource<<" i: "<<i<<"\n";
            printf("\nthread 1 is working on resource: %d and i: %d", resource, i);
            resource++;
//            cout<<"thread 1 work completed, new value: "<<resource<<"\n";
            printf("\nthread 1 work completed, new value: %d and i: %d", resource, i);
            c1.notify_one();
            lk1.unlock();
//            printf("\nvalue of count before incr %d", count);
            count++;
            printf("\nvalue of count %d", count);
//            cout<<"count while exec for t1: "<<count<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            c1.wait(lk1);
//            cout<<"count while waiting for t1: "<<count<<endl;
        }
    }
}

void func2()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
//        lock1.lock();
        unique_lock <mutex> lk1(lock1);
        if(count == 1)
        {
//            cout<<"thread 2 is working on resource: "<<resource<<" i: "<<i<<"\n";
            printf("\nthread 2 is working on resource: %d and i: %d", resource, i);
            resource--;
//            cout<<"thread 2 work completed, new value: "<<resource<<"\n";
            printf("\nthread 2 work completed, new value: %d and i: %d", resource, i);
            c1.notify_one();
            lk1.unlock();
//            printf("\nvalue of count before decr %d", count);
            count--;
            printf("\nvalue of count %d", count);
//            cout<<"count while exec for t2: "<<count<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            c1.wait(lk1);
//            cout<<"count while waiting for t2: "<<count<<endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    thread worker1(func1);
    thread worker2(func2);
    cout<<"\nthread started"<<endl;
    worker1.join();
    worker2.join();
    cout<<"\nthread completed"<<endl;
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    cout<<duration.count();
}
```

**i dont know why the position of the printf is acting as a pivot for the program's ability to run**, i wrote it simply to see why the program was not executing completely by printing the value of count at each step and then the program magically executed completely. sorry if the problem is caused by something extremely trivial, blame it on my 2 neurons that are left to do all the work (only 2 threads at a time lol).

Comment: once you called `lk1.unlock();` there is no synchronization between two threads accessing `count`.

Comment: Could be line buffering maybe. what if you call fflush afterwards or put the \n at the end?

Comment: btw your way to format comments is rahter unusual and not very readable

Comment: @RicherCritten they are calling `lk1.unlock()` only once. Destructor of `lk1` unlocks only when the mutex is still locked otherwise does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
            lk1.unlock();
            count++;
```

Both execution threads have this identical code. Both execution threads release the `lock1` mutex and update `count` without proper synchronization, without holding a mutex lock. This is undefined behavior. You cannot expect any specific results from the shown program.

Comment: okay i somewhat understand this, so i think that i should update the value of count inside the lock and then release the lock ?

Comment: Every object that's accessed from multiple threads which gets updated must be properly synchronized. The simplest form of synchronization is having every execution thread hold the same mutex lock while accessing the object.

Comment: sure, but why does the program work when the printf after count++ or count-- is uncommented?

Comment: @ririririri You can check the assembly code produced by your compiler with the flags you selected. But it's an useless effort. It's **undefined behavior**, meaning that the compiler is free to do whatever it likes.

Comment: @ririririri your code has undefined behavior. Getting expected output does not mean it is right. Correct code produces correct output always not just sometimes.